# Is it necessary to initialize the char array for accurate length?

Tags: c, string

In the below example when I define char array uninitialized and want to find the length, it's undefined behavior.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
char a[250];
printf("length=%d\n",strlen(a));
}
```

I got "0". I don't know how? Explain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luck. Whether it's good or bad luck is a matter of opinion. The contents of your array are whatever happened to already occupy that memory, and is not initialized.  In your case, it happened the first byte was a `'\0'`.

This is, of course, undefined behavior and you can't depend on it happening this way.

Comment: It isn't necessarily luck; some compilers may initialize unset local variables as happens with global ones, it just isn't a requirement for compilers to do so (hence why it's undefined behavior) and as such that behavior shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: @JAB: Interesting point. Although I've not run across such a compiler, I can't think of anything that would forbid the compiler from doing it.

Comment: It's ok but sometimes when i increase the length of array sometimes it's show 1 or 2 or 3.

char a[300];
it's show the result =3.
this is have the same explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You said in your example you were using an uninitialized char array to show undefined behavior, then when you got "0" you want an explanation? It's... undefined behavior.

If you got 0 for the length if just means that there happens to be a 0 as the first element of `a[]` in your uninitialized array. When it's an uninitialized local that means, as far as the C standards are concerened, anything can be in there, including a 0.

---

To address the question in your title: "Is it necessary to initialize the char array for accurate length?"

Yes, to be able to deterministically know the length of a string in a char array via the `strlen()` function, it is required for a null terminator to be present. That means it needs to be initialized or set in some manner or another.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers say the strlen() result is more a matter of luck than defined behaviour

To find the "size" of the memory block use sizeof() instead

*Note*: I've also included the `string.h` and used a long conversion for the integers in the `printf`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
 int main()
 {
     char a[250];
     printf("length=%ld\n",strlen(a));
     printf("sizeof=%ld\n",sizeof(a));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

when you define

```
char a[250];
```

The array will contains garabage contents and random.

`strlen(a)` count the number of not null charachter (`'\0'`) till it find a null charachter then it stop.

so if your `char a[250];` array contains garabage element and the first element is randomly set to null `'\0'` the `strlen(a)` will return 0